# How to detect on which part of screen (left or right) is an event in React big calendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want to create a tooltip, but it overflows if the event located on the right side, so i need to detect an event position somehow.

Comment: Pls show your code

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event object you can find different properties like `screenX`, `screenY`, `pageX`, `pageY`, `clientX` and `clientY` etc which can give you mouse position relative to screen, page and client.